# Android, When user installs an app?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to know when users installs a new app. I have used broadcast receiver.

```
<receiver android:name=".NewInstallReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.package_added" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Code:

```
public class NewInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String act = intent.getAction();
        Log.e("ee", "new install" + intent);
        if (Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED.equals(act) || Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED.equals(act)) {
            /* ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
            contentResolver.query()*/
        }
    }
}
```

I see no logs when i install app from playstore.

Should I use service? If yes then how can i make it run for infinite times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is typo in your intent filter, try  below intent filter

```
<receiver android:name=".NewInstallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>            
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>  
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Sure, as a side note, I trust Eclipse/Android studio to auto complete these codes in XML and in Java. Ctrl + Space should give you what options to pick while editing which is always preferable then typing manually!! Thanks!

Comment: I am sure I did the same way.